# Securing a forms Authentication Internet site

Tags: 2007, security

I have an internet site using MOSS 2007/win 2008/SQL 2005.
Users are authenticated using forms authentication.

All authenticated users are able to browse pages like:
/Style%20Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx  or
_layouts/viewlsts.apsx

They can view XSL files and even download a copy of it.

How can I restrict users from accessing these pages without affecting their browsing experience?

Note: I have activated the ViewFormPagesLockdown feature and made sure anonymous users are not able to access these pages.

Answer (score 1):

As you say ViewFormPagesLockdown affects anonymous users only. What the feature really does is remove ViewFormPages right from Limited Access role:

```
SPRoleDefinition guest = mySite.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Guest);
guest.BasePermissions &= ~(SPBasePermissions.EmptyMask | SPBasePermissions.ViewFormPages);
guest.BasePermissions &= ~SPBasePermissions.UseRemoteAPIs;
guest.Update();
```

You could use the same code to remove these permissions for the role types you dont want this access to.

Comment: you mean i need to create an EXE for example that does this action and run it against the sites that need to be secured?

Comment: i would probably go for a call-out (feature receiver) that modified the role. This gives you both better provisioning and the possibility to reset the rights on feature deactivation:
guest.BasePermissions |= SPBasePermissions.EmptyMask | SPBasePermissions.ViewFormPages;
guest.BasePermissions |= SPBasePermissions.UseRemoteAPIs;

what you will need to determine first though is what SPRoleType you want to revoke these permissions from...